# print each ip address with number of GET /PUT /POST /DELETe request in perl

Tags: regex, perl, ip-address

I have a apache log which looks like below.

192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "PUT /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0"

10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "POST /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0"

192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:09:04:09 +0000] "GET /apps/cart.jsp?appID=4651 HTTP/1.0"

192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:09:04:09 +0000] "GET /apps/cart.jsp?appID=4651 HTTP/1.0"

10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "POST /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0"

---

It consists of same ip address multiple times with different reqeust types.
Can any give a solution in perl to extract all the ip address,group them and no of POST/GET/DELETE request for each ip address.
Output format should be like

192.168.10.20: GET=23,POST=13,PUT=23,DELETE=11

43.56.76.4: GET=4,POST=3,PUT=1,DELETE=3

Till now I have done this, extracted ip and request type and logged into another file and then counted of each occurance:

```
my $file = "apache_log.log";
my $file2 = "apache_log1.log";
my %hrec;
open (FH, "$file");
open(DATA, ">$file2");
my $str;
while (my $line = <FH>) {
chomp $line;
if  ( $line =~ /^(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,})\s+\-\s+\-\s+\[\d{1,}\/\w+\/\d{1,}\:\d{1,}\:\d{1,}\:\d{1,}\s+\+0000\]\s+\"(PUT|GET|POST|DELETE)/)   {
print DATA "$1: $2\n";
}
close(DATA);
close(FH);
open(DATA, "$file2") or die "Couldn't open file $file2, $!";
while ( my $str = <DATA>) {
my @requests = split ('\n',$str);
foreach my $req(@requests) {
$hrec{$req}++;
 }
 }
close(DATA);
foreach my $fam ( sort keys %hrec) {
print "$fam =". ($hrec{$fam})."\n";
}
```

--
But my output is coming like below
192.168.10.20: GET=23

192.168.10.20: POST=16

43.56.76.4: GET=4

43.56.76.4: POST=3

and so on.``

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a code writing service. The OP just provided the problem and showed no attempts to solve it himself.

Comment: Regexp::Log::Common

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ..sorry for that..I had tried and now pasted my program. Will be helpful if you could help.

Comment: @SaketKumar: I suggest that you look at your badly formatted post and look at ways how it can be properly formatted. There are ways to properly format code etc. Make your post readable by others if you expect others to invest their free time to help you.

Comment: Use a two-level hash as datastructure. Then iterate your logfile, pick the IP and the method from each line and do `$num_requests{$ip}{$method} += 1;`.

Comment: thanks , used same thing and it's working now

Comment: @SaketKumar please read _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)._

Answer (score 1):

```
open(FileHandle, "<$ARGV[0]");
%hash = ();
while(<FileHandle>)
{
    chomp($_);
    if($_ =~ /^(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}.\d{1,})/) { $ip = $1; }
    if($_ =~ /GET/) { $hash{$ip}{"GET"}++; }
    if($_ =~ /POST/) { $hash{$ip}{"POST"}++; }
    if($_ =~ /PUT/) { $hash{$ip}{"PUT"}++; }
    if($_ =~ /DELETE/) { $hash{$ip}{"DELETE"}++; }
}
foreach $k (keys %hash)
{
    print "$k: GET=$hash{$k}{'GET'},POST=$hash{$k}{'POST'},PUT=$hash{$k}{'PUT'},DELETE=$hash{$k}{'DELETE'}\n";
}
```

Comment: perl prog.pl <input your apache log file>

Comment: @SaketKumar If it worked then please select my answer as correct solution so that others having same problem can also use it. Thanks

Comment: **Allways** `use strict; use warnings;`